# Python on OSX, error about site-packages folder

Tags: python, three.js, osx-mountain-lion, maya

I'm trying to run a python script to convert an FBX model from Maya to a ThreeJS JSON loadable module. I'm running OSX Mountain Lion. Whenever I try to run the script, I get the following error:

```
You need to copy the content in compatible subfolder under /lib/python<version> into your
python install folder such as "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages" folder.
```

Anyone ever run into that problem and/or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently, the `site-packages` directory resides in `/Library/Python/2.6`